# How to reduce cost after a car accident at fault and no insurance

Tags: car-insurance

There is an at-fault car without insurance (on suspended license) crashed into another car and caused damage to both cars. No injuries.

Comment: Do you mean the value of the car? The cost is still what you paid for it.

Comment: "*The car is involved*".  That's a very passive statement.  Were **you** driving it, and hit another car, or was it just sitting there and magically plowed into another car?

Comment: what country/state do you live in? In the US insurance regulations vary by state. Were you required to have insurance?

Comment: You should put a country tag. In some countries there would be no insurance company involved because you would be fined by government agency who would also pursue you for any amount of money that the victim would have to cover.

Comment: You cannot drive a car without insurance, it is a crime. Do you mean insurance claim of your car?

Comment: @mootmoot That depends on where the OP lives, which seems to not be mentioned.

Comment: Assuming you are in the UK, driving without insurance is a very serious matter. Even having your car available to be driven at any time, without insurance, is a very serious matter.

Comment: Hi guys, I just edited my question. Thanks for the comments and you are all right. Everyone must drive a car with an insurance.

Comment: Hi noob - your edit made it so there really isn't a question any more. Is there something you were actually trying to ask? If you feel you feel your question got answered, you should accept the answer below, but still leave your question as an actual question.

Comment: Which country is this in? Australia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the UK, if you damaged my car, I would inform my insurance and leave it to them. They will send someone out who checks what repairs need doing, they can do the repairs for me, give me a courtesy car while I'm waiting for my car, and send the bill to your insurance. Or since you don't have insurance, they send it to you.

What they are *not* going to do is ask *you* about your opinion what repairs are necessary. And they *will* make you pay. It can take a while, but you *will* pay.

Don't drive without insurance. It can be expensive. It can destroy you financially. And nobody outside your family feels in any way bad about it if that happens to you.

If you can't afford insurance, sell your car. Use public transport, or a bicycle, or get a taxi. Don't drive without insurance.